# .NET Core 1.1 ExecuteSqlCommand with Parameters containing Single Quotes

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

When using .ExecuteSqlCommand if parameter contains single quotes I get the following error:

> A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate \"Insert_Log_Error\": \r\nSystem.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near 's'.

Before the 's' there is a single quote in the parameter.

```
            SqlParameter processName = new SqlParameter("@ProcessName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            SqlParameter className = new SqlParameter("@ClassName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            SqlParameter methodName = new SqlParameter("@MethodName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            SqlParameter lineNumber = new SqlParameter("@LineNumber", SqlDbType.SmallInt);
            SqlParameter message = new SqlParameter("@Message", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            SqlParameter innerMessage = new SqlParameter("@InnerMessage", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            SqlParameter fullMessage = new SqlParameter("@FullMessage", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            SqlParameter sqlLevel = new SqlParameter("@LogLevel", SqlDbType.SmallInt);
            SqlParameter sqlCreatedDate = new SqlParameter("@CreatedDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            SqlParameter sqlCreatedBy = new SqlParameter("@CreatedBy", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            SqlParameter sqlMachineId = new SqlParameter("@MachineId", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            SqlParameter sqlMachineType = new SqlParameter("@MachineType", SqlDbType.SmallInt);

            processName.Value = strace.GetFrame(frame).GetMethod().Module.Name;
            className.Value = strace.GetFrame(frame).GetMethod().ReflectedType.FullName;
            methodName.Value = strace.GetFrame(frame).GetMethod().Name;
            lineNumber.Value = strace.GetFrame(frame).GetFileLineNumber();
            message.Value = exception.Message;
            innerMessage.Value = exception.InnerException != null ? (object)exception.InnerException.Message : DBNull.Value;
            fullMessage.Value = exception.ToString();
            sqlLevel.Value = level;
            sqlCreatedDate.Value = DateTime.Now;
            sqlCreatedBy.Value = createdBy;
            sqlMachineId.Value = machineId;
            sqlMachineType.Value = machineType;

            _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand
                (
                    "EXECUTE [dbo].[Insert_Log_Error] @ProcessName, @ClassName, @MethodName, @LineNumber, @Message, @InnerMessage, @FullMessage, @LogLevel, @CreatedDate, @CreatedBy, @MachineId, @MachineType",
                    parameters: new[]
                    {
                        processName,
                        className,
                        methodName,
                        lineNumber,
                        message,
                        innerMessage,
                        fullMessage,
                        sqlLevel,
                        sqlCreatedDate,
                        sqlCreatedBy,
                        sqlMachineId,
                        sqlMachineType
                    }
                );
```

For it to work I have to add .Replace("'", "''") for every string parameter as it can contain single quotes which is far from ideal.

Comment: Try to pass parameters: `ExecuteSqlCommand("sql", new SqlParameter("@ProcessName", processName), new SqlParameter("@ClassName", className) ...)`

Comment: i think you pass the values directly without being wrapped in SqlParameters. Not sure if that matters though, because i've never used [`ExecuteSqlCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand%28System.String,System.Object[]%29)

Comment: added all code, I am passing SqlParameters

Comment: What was the real error message? If i google "there is a single quote in the parameter" i find only your post. Show the sql of `Insert_Log_Error`

Comment: well... that's why I'm posting because I couldn't find any related issues. The problem is that single quote is a reserved character in SQL and when EF is converting the parameter translates something like this: EXECUTE [dbo].[Insert_Log_Error] 'Process name', 'Class name', 'method name', 84, 'Error here's single quote', NULL, 'Full error message', 1, '2016-01-01 14:15:43', 'username', 'MachineId', 1

Comment: How do you know how EF translates it?

Comment: I just switched on SQL Profiler, and notice that EF is translating it properly. The problem is in the stored procedure. My fault, thanks for the help :)